# Python-Kivy: BoxLayout with stretch capability

Tags: python, kivy

How can I make my boxlayout expand according to dynamically added content?
Here is my code to illustrate what I am trying to do:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TestApp(App):

    def add_label(self):
        label = Label(text='StackOverflow', color=(0,0,0,1))
        self.root.ids.myBox.add_widget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 400

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(280), dp(100)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        #width: self.minimum_width
        #height: self.minimum_height
        id: myBox
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    Button:
        text: 'BUTTON'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(100), dp(50)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: app.add_label()
```

The button has the effect of dynamically adding a label to the boxlayout. But the more the labels are added, the size of the boxlayout does not change and the texts are superimposed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is do recalculate the size of the `BoxLayout` yourself. By changing your `add_label()` method to:

```
def add_label(self):
    label = Label(text='StackOverflow', color=(0,0,0,1))
    self.root.ids.myBox.add_widget(label)
    label.texture_update()
    boxlayout = self.root.ids.myBox
    height = 0
    for child in boxlayout.children:
        height += child.texture_size[1]
        height += 2 * child.padding_y
    boxlayout.height = height
```

The `BoxLayout` changes height on each `Label` addition. You would think that you could use the `child.height` in the calculation, but the default value for height is always 100 until the layout is actually calculated. But, as you have seen, when the layout is calculated, the height of the label is reduced to fit in the `BoxLayout`. The texture of the `Label` can be updated before layout, and therefore, I have used its height in the calculation. This will decrease the size of the `BoxLayout` with the first `Label` added, and will increase it on every following addition. Note that this will only work for widgets that have a `texture` property like the `Label` or `Button`.